Swift UI DatePicker hourAndMinute fails when another picker is displaying menu
Does any one know a workaround (as I assume this is a bug).
Trying to open Time portion of DatePicker while another menu styled picker is opened breaks the whole DatePicker:

The Time menu does not open.
The Time part changes color to foreground color.
The Date part also stops working and changes color to foreground after tapping.

Video from simulator iPhone 15 Pro (17.5).
Reproduced on iPhone 13 Pro (iOS 17.5.1).
struct DatePickerIssueView: View {
    @State private var date: Date = Date()
    @State private var option: String = "Option 1"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            DatePicker(
                "",
                selection: $date,
                displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
            )
            Spacer()
            Picker("", selection: $option) {
                ForEach([
                    "Option 1",
                    "Option 2"
                ], id: \.self) { optionValue in
                    Text(optionValue)
                        .tag(optionValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


